# Can I fake a video stream in Zoom (or fake it using packets so as to work universally)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, packet, packet-capture, intercept

Currently, I have yet to find anything online using Google. However, what I'm trying to do is to take a pre recorded photo or video, and intercept my camera's capture. Similar effect to holding up a printed photo to a camera. Also similar to spy-type movies like James Bond/007, or like in the first National Treasure. I would prefer to use python, however, I do understand the basics of Java and C++. This is mainly for Google Meet and Zoom. I prefer to directly manipulate the camera.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: maybe you could set up a fake camera driver

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/681386/webcam-driver-that-uses-an-image-or-video-file-as-the-video-source if you just want to use a video file or static image. If you want to programmatically manipulate the video stream, writing your own virtual camera device driver (or finding an open source one to modify) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Lots of hardware devices available that will take an arbitrary HDMI input and act like a webcam; none of them on-topic on SO, though. Similarly, a lot of  input-switching hardware supports preloading static images and using them as targets to switch to -- see Blackmagic Design's ATEM mini for one example that serves both roles (webcam emulation, and insertion of static content).

Comment: ...even insofar as you're willing to write some code, Stack Overflow questions need to be about a _narrow, specific_ problem you actually face -- which is to say, you need to have actually started writing the tool and hit a problem along the way to be able to ask it in enough detail to allow a canonical, non-speculative answer.

Comment: for zoom call [zoom video looper](https://github.com/adithyan-ak/ZoomVideoLooper) this is solution

Comment: Thank you @kwatford I used the splitcam, It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve this with programming, I did however find this article about fake attending a Zoom meeting using a pre-recorded video and play it as the virtual background. Maybe it will help you.

Link to Article: https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2020/05/11/fake-attend-boring-zoom-meeting/

Comment: Questions that aren't about programming as defined in the help center should be closed, not answered. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section titled *Answer Well-Asked Questions*.